# Unable to transmit fast via UDP broadcast on a wireless network

Tags: c++, sockets, posix, wireless, openwrt

I have the written the following code for transmitting UDP packets via broadcasting on a wireless network. The application that I have trying to develop requires the packets to be transmitted very fast, but unfortunately I cannot do so and need to add a sleep time. I find that below 500us sleep time, I am unable to send all the packets successfully.

1. Why does the sleep time have to be so high?
2. Is it possible to reduce this time by further optimization of this code?
3. If I do not process the received packets buffer, is it okay? Or does this create problems?

Note that I am running this code on a wireless radio which runs using [OpenWrt](http://openwrt.org/).

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in */

#define BROADCAST_IP "192.168.255.255"
#define BROADCAST_PORT 45454

int b_sock=-1;

void init_socket()
{
  unsigned short b_port = BROADCAST_PORT;
  struct sockaddr_in b_addr;
  int broadcastPermission;
  char* rx_ip = BROADCAST_IP;

  if ((b_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
    perror("socket() failed");

  /* Set socket to allow broadcast */
  broadcastPermission = 1;
  if (setsockopt(b_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void *) &broadcastPermission, sizeof(broadcastPermission)) < 0)
    perror("setsockopt() failed");

  int opts;
  opts = fcntl(b_sock,F_GETFL);
  if(opts < 0)
    perror("fcntl get failed");

  opts = (opts | O_NONBLOCK);
  if(fcntl(b_sock,F_SETFL,opts) < 0)
    perror("fcntl set failed");

  memset(&b_addr, 0, sizeof(b_addr));   /* Zero out structure */
  b_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 /* Internet address family */
  b_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(rx_ip);/* Broadcast IP address */
  b_addr.sin_port = htons(b_port);         /* Broadcast port */

  if (bind(b_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &b_addr, sizeof(b_addr)) < 0)
    perror("rx bind() failed");
}

void send_thread_body(long int buf, struct sockaddr_in tx_addr)
{
  if(sendto(b_sock, &buf, sizeof(long int), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&tx_addr, sizeof(tx_addr)) < 0)
    printf("tx sent diff num bytes than expected: %d\n",buf);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  init_socket();
  {
    timeval start, end;
    double diff = 0;
    long int num = 0;

    char *tx_ip = BROADCAST_IP;
    unsigned short tx_port = BROADCAST_PORT;
    struct sockaddr_in tx_addr;

    memset(&tx_addr, 0, sizeof(tx_addr));   /* Zero out structure */
    tx_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 /* Internet address family */
    tx_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(tx_ip);/* Broadcast IP address */
    tx_addr.sin_port = htons(tx_port);         /* Broadcast port */

    double next = 0;
    double st = 0;

    while (num<50000)
    {
      while (st <= next)
      {
        gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
        st = start.tv_sec*1000 + ((double)start.tv_usec)/1000.0;
      }

      send_thread_body(num,tx_addr);

      gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
      diff += ((double)(((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)*1000000 + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec))))/1000000.0;

      num++;

      next = end.tv_sec*1000 + ((double)end.tv_usec)/1000.0 + 0.7;
    }

    printf("Avg time diff: %f\n",diff/50000.0);
  }
  close(b_sock);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: UDP is not a reliable protocol...  You have to be able to tolerate dropped packets in general.

Comment: What data do you actually need to send?  How are you determining that sending is failing?  Is it failing internally on the sending computer, or are packets dropped elsewhere on the network?  Can you send more data per datagram by framing the data at the application layer?

Comment: @Nemo: Yes, I can tolerate some packet loss but not excessive packet loss.

Comment: @John: The data that I actually need to send is an object of a structure, but currently I have replaced it with transmitting just a variable of type long. I have found that it is failing because it gives me the error "tx sent diff num bytes than expected". This code runs directly on a wireless modem, not on a computer. The packets are sent from one such modem/radio to another. It is not possible for me to club data in my application, and hence I need to send them as it is.

Comment: What is errno set to when the sendto() fails, e.g. ENOBUFS?

Comment: Note that multicasting (and therefore, I assume, broadcasting) over WiFi isn't very fast or efficient, as described here:  http://serverfault.com/questions/168567/why-are-my-listener-less-multicast-packets-affecting-wifi-performance/168729#168729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably overflowing the socket buffer because you set the socket to `O_NONBLOCK`. Normally (when blocking is enabled), if the socket buffer is full, `sendto` blocks until there is sufficient buffer space to hold the message for sending.

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html:

> If space is not available at the
>   sending socket to hold the message to
>   be transmitted and the socket file
>   descriptor does not have O_NONBLOCK
>   set, sendto() shall block until space
>   is available. If space is not
>   available at the sending socket to
>   hold the message to be transmitted and
>   the socket file descriptor does have
>   O_NONBLOCK set, sendto() shall fail.

When you added `sleep`s between your `sendto` calls, you were effectively throttling down the throughput and preventing the socket buffers from overflowing.

Instead of `sleep`, you should use a blocking socket. If the socket buffers become full, `sendto` will block, which is effectively the same thing as sleeping, except that it will automatically stop sleeping the instant the socket is able to hold your next datagram.

To achieve better thoughput, try lumping data into datagrams close to the MTU size (while taking care to save enough room for UDP/IP headers). This should give you smaller header overhead compared to sending very short datagrams.

Comment: I changed to blocking mode, and it definitely improves the performance by 10 times. But when I try out a test which involves simultaneous transmission and receiving of broadcast messages on the same modem/radio, the results are more or less the same. Any idea why this is so? How can I improve the performance? How can I reduce the loss of packets. Current packet loss is about 15% between transmission and receiving. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have any experience with OpenWrt, or your particular hardware. I only have (limited) knowledge in socket programming. OpenWrt's forum (https://forum.openwrt.org/) seems to be pretty active. You might get more relevant help there. Make sure to include information about your hardware.

Comment: Is your sending and receiving code running in separate threads? If not, you might have to use `select` to multiplex both send and receive operations within the same thread.

Comment: I am sending and receiving in different threads using pthreads. I wasnt aware of "select", and hence had not considered that possibility. I will also post it into the OpenWrt forums, and see if there is some issue specific to OpenWrt, but currently I do not feel thats the case. Thank you very much for your help. :-)